# nodejs best way to convert an input file to json format

Tags: node.js, json, file

I have an input file.txt that takes the following format

```
Order: Order1
from customerA to customerB
orderItemA
orderItemB

Order: Order2
from customerC to customerD
orderItemC
orderItemD
```

I want to convert this total input into a json and then start processing it.  At the moment all I can think of is to read this line by line and then start to process it, but is there any node package or an alternative way in which I can read the whole file in one go and convert it to a JSON format ? I found the following but did not work https://www.npmjs.com/package/plain-text-data-to-json

Comment: it would be better if you read the file line by line and use JSON.parse to convert to object write to file.

Comment: json.parse would only work if the input is in strict json format as far as I know, this is not so.